# Subgroup of order $4$ in $D_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let me ask you a question on group theory which confuses me.

Consider the group $D_8$ the dihedral group of order $8$ generated by $\sigma$ and $\tau$ with $o(\sigma)=4,o(\tau)=2$ and $\tau\sigma=\sigma^{-1}\tau$.

Consider the following elements, namely $\sigma\tau$ and $\tau$ which have order equal to $2$.
Then $\langle\tau\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\langle\sigma\tau\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ then $\langle\tau\rangle \times \langle\sigma\tau\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. We know that $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is Klein group.
But I checked that the set $\langle\tau\rangle \times \langle\sigma\tau\rangle$ is not even group because $\tau\sigma\tau=\sigma^{-1}$ which does not belong to this set.

Where is the problem?

Would be very grateful for explanation!

Comment: I guess you want $\sigma$, say, of order $4$, otherwise you get indeed the Klein four-group, not $D_{8}$

Comment: If you seek a Klein subgroup, consider $\langle \tau \rangle \langle \sigma^2 \rangle$ instead. This is indeed a subgroup because $\langle \sigma^2 \rangle$ is normal in $D_8$.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, $\langle\tau\rangle\times \langle\sigma\tau\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$. But it is just not a subgroup of the dihedral group. The elements of $\langle\tau\rangle\times \langle\sigma\tau\rangle$ are ordered pairs of elements of $D_4$, so it is a subgroup of $D_4\times D_4$. Though $D_4$ really has a subgroup which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$, check $\langle \sigma^2,\tau\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But some things are still unclear to me. If its isomorphic to Klein group then it is group. But as wee this is not group since not closed. Could you explain more in detais? I would be very grateful for that!

Comment: Yes, $\langle\tau\rangle\times\langle\sigma\tau\rangle$ is a group with respect to operation in every coordinate. Direct product of groups is always a group. Maybe you are confusing between $\langle\tau\rangle\times\langle\sigma\tau\rangle$ and $\langle\tau\rangle\langle\sigma\tau\rangle$? Well, $\langle\tau\rangle\langle\sigma\tau\rangle$ is really not a group and hence it is of course not isomorphic to Klein group.

Comment: @RFZ (Sorry, fixing an error in my previous comment.) $\langle \tau \rangle \times \langle \sigma \tau \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$. But $\langle \tau \rangle \times \langle \sigma \tau \rangle$ is an **external** direct product. $D_4$ doesn't contain $\langle \tau \rangle \times \langle \sigma \tau \rangle$. It does contain the product $\langle \tau \rangle \langle \sigma \tau \rangle$. But this product isn't even a subgroup, let alone a direct product.

Comment: In general, if $G$ is a group and $H$ and $K$ are subgroups, then you can always form the product $HK$ as a subset of $G$, but this isn't guaranteed to be a subgroup unless at least one of $H$ or $K$ is normal. (In your case, neither $\langle \tau \rangle$ nor $\langle \sigma \tau \rangle$ is normal.) And even if $HK$ is a subgroup, it is not isomorphic to $H \times K$ unless $H$ and $K$ are **both** normal and $H \cap K = 1$.

Comment: @Bungo, one of the groups being normal is not necessary though. $HK$ is a subgroup if and only if $HK=KH$. One of $H$ and $K$ being normal in $G$ just makes it happen for sure.

Comment: @Mark Yep, normality of $H$ or $K$ is sufficient but not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mistake is to assume that $\tau$ and $\tau \sigma$ commute. This is not the case
$$
\tau \cdot \tau \sigma = \sigma,
$$
while
$$
\tau \sigma \cdot \tau = \sigma^{-1} \tau \tau = \sigma^{-1} \ne \sigma.
$$